# How to install natbib in Miktex?

Tags: natbib

I'm currently using Bibtex for by bibliography with Mendeley. I'm trying to use natbib. But after hours of research, I failed to figure out how to install it. I'm kind of new to tex, Latex, etc. Do you know where I can find a manual that instructs me one by one how to install and use natbib? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which distribution do you have ?

Comment: I have downloaded natbib.tar from the following site: http://www.biochem.ucl.ac.uk/~james/latex/bibliography.html

Comment: @ppp - This doesn't answer Bernard's question. Which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: Almost any reasonable tex distribution will have natbib installed or at worse allow it to install automatically from a package manager, you should not have to fetch it "by hand"

Comment: to use `natbib` you will also need a tex distribution.  most tex distributions nowadays are based on tex live, and tex live already contains `natbib` in usable form.  if you have such a (full) distribution, you can access the documentation by typing (at a command line prompt) `texdoc natbib`/

Comment: I am using Miktex. (I'm not sure if this is a right answer.) Does this have natbib installed? Then how do I use it?

Comment: Yes, MikTeX is a TeX distribution. If you've set up MikTeX so that it automatically accesses an Internet repository the first time it encounters a request for `<some_package>` (usually via a `\usepackage{<some_package>}` statement), you should let MikTeX do its own thing. If that doesn't work, fire up the MikTeX Package Manager (MPM) app and tell it to download and install `natbib`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MiKTeX has a `package manager`. Launch it as administrator, select `natbib` in the list of packages. Click on `+`in the toolbar to install it, as in this screenshot:

[image]

Alternatively, as Mico said, MiKTeX can install missing packages on the fly.

Comment: I have just tried these and it seems natbib is already installed. While I can select `-` (i.e. uninstall) I cannot select `+` (i.e. install). Then can I just start to use natbib in my text editor (Texmaker)? How do I do so? (Sorry for all these newbie questions.)

Comment: It is working now! Problem resolved! Thank you all!

Comment: @ppp - One typically loads a package via a `\usepackage` statement, e.g., `\usepackage{natbib}`, in the document's preamble. A package generally provides macros, e.g, `\citet` and `\citep` in the case of `natbib`, and sometimes environments. Please consult a document such as [The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX2e](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) to get started with LaTeX. You'll really learn a lot.

Comment: I would advise to use `biblatex` instead of `natbib`, as it has more possibilities and works with `biber`, a replacement for `bibtex` based on perl which understands `utf8` encoded .bib files.

Comment: @Bernard best to qualify that advice, a great many journals will be using bibtex but not (yet?) biblatex/biber of course for a personal document different considerations apply.

Comment: @Bernard It says HTTP Error 503 when I try to install this package natbib.

Comment: @Anand: If you tried to install  the package today, the package repository is offline due to errors in the last update. I think it will be solved tomorrow.